# How to set a authenticated user web session for sending rest requests

Tags: rest, session, restful-authentication

I want to test an API which has the followoing instruction:

`This API requires the caller to have an authenticated user web session.`

When I login to the application and send a GET request in other tab it works. But I want to send a PUT request now so I cannot use browser. How can I have an authenticated user session while sending request through some other rest client. For  eg: postman/ mozilla rest client.

I have tried logging into application through chrome and then using postman rest client. But it did not work. I have also tried Basic authentication providing application username and password.

Comment: Please clarify what mechanism you're using for sessions. Cookies, JWT, Basic Auth…?

Comment: I am using JWT for authentication

Answer (score 0):

So, given you mentioned you're using `JWT`, your API is most likely handing out this token upon logging in. At this moment your web client (javascript?) is probably storing it somewhere (cookie, local storage, session storage… – you can use your browser's dev tools to inspect). For all subsequent requests, this token is attached. If this token is getting persisted as a cookie, the browser itself takes care of attaching it to every request. If it is persisted somewhere else, your client has to "manually" attach this token to every request.

If you want to test your API call, first you need to login and get your hands on the token. Then, for all authenticated requests, you need to attach this token (probably as the `Authorization` HTTP header).